# Spring boot - MongoDb getting a ClassNotFoundException on RepositoryInvokerFactory

Tags: java, mongodb, maven, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I am trying to set up a Spring boot application with MongoDB connection to mLab. But when I try to run this test (or any other test)

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest 

public class SyncrewApplicationTests {
  @Test
  public void contextLoads() {
  } 
}
```

I get this error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.data.rest.core.invoke.RepositoryInvokerFactory
```

My Spring boot application:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class SyncrewApplication {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(SyncrewApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

The user MongoDB repository

```
@RepositoryRestResource(exported = false)
public interface UserRepository extends MongoRepository<User, Integer> {
    User findUserByUsername(String username);
    User findUserByEmail(String email);
}
```

User class

```
@Document(collection = "users")
public class User implements Serializable, UserDetails {
    @Id
    private String id;

    private String username;

    public User(){}

    public User(String username){
        this.username = username;
    }
    // getters and setters
```

I think my problem is in my pom.xml but I don't know where.. This are my dependencies

```
<dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hsqldb</groupId>
            <artifactId>hsqldb</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-data-rest-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.1.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>ma.glasnost.orika</groupId>
            <artifactId>orika-core</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.5</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

Comment: Do you have mongodb downloaded and running when u run this application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your files seems perfect just add versions in the pom and It should work.

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb</artifactId>
        <version>RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        <version>RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        <version>RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hsqldb</groupId>
        <artifactId>hsqldb</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
        <version>RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-data-rest-webmvc</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.1.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>ma.glasnost.orika</groupId>
        <artifactId>orika-core</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.5</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
        <version>RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>
```

RELEASE =1.5.1.RELEASE

Comment: Yes, this fixed it! Thanks!